# Converting from Gregorian calendar to the Persian calendar is not working

Tags: c#, persian-calendar

In my code, I want to convert from the Gregorian calendar (ex: 2019/10/8) to the Persian calendar (ex: 1398/07/16).
Here is my code:

```
public static string ToPersianDate(this DateTime t)
{
    var pc = new PersianCalendar();
    return $"{pc.GetYear(t)}/{pc.GetMonth(t)}/{pc.GetDayOfMonth(t)}";
}
```

but what I get is the same date I pass as input parameter!

I mean if I pass 2019/10/08 I will get 2019/10/08. It seems as if no conversion ever happened.

Comment: How are you calling this?  Your code seems to work for me, it returns `1398/7/27` for todays date.

Comment: @haldo this way: itemDto.Name = Convert.ToDateTime(itemDto.Name).ToPersianDate();

Comment: Here's a working [fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/WVAJDf). Can you provide a [mre]?

Answer (score 1):

You could try the following code to convert Gregorian date to Persian date.

```
    string GregorianDate = "2019/10/08";
    DateTime d = DateTime.Parse(GregorianDate);
    PersianCalendar pc = new PersianCalendar();
    Console.WriteLine(string.Format("{0}/{1}/{2}", pc.GetYear(d), pc.GetMonth(d), pc.GetDayOfMonth(d)));
```

Result:
[image]

Comment: This is effectively the same code that's in the question, but with an extra conversion to start with. The original code should already work - adding an extra conversion first isn't going to help that. We need to find out more about why the existing code isn't working for the OP.

Comment: both codes are the same, and it dosn't change the output. Even by changing region setting to persian it didn't work!